# Spin up a Cloud9 environment through CloudFormation template with an existing EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

My goal should be evident from the question. The issue lies in my inability to locate an AMI suitable for ARM core machines. I aim to establish an SSH connection to my EC2 instance. Is it feasible to connect to ARM-based machines?